# Deserialization using jackson mapper annotations in java

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following `json` using `Jackson` annotations. Here is my current code:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "serviceType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StripeServiceConfiguration.class, name = "Stripe"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BrainServiceConfiguration.class, name = "Brain"),
})
public interface ServiceConfiguration {
  TypeOfService getServiceType();
}
```

## StripeService

```java
    @Data
    public class StripeServiceConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
      private static final TypeOfService serviceType = TypeOfService.STRIPE;
      private Map<String, Object> jsonConfiguration;

      @Override
      public TypeOfService getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
      }
    }
```

## OtherPaymentService

```java
    @Data
    public class BrainServiceConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
      private static final TypeOfService serviceType = TypeOfService.BRAIN;
      private Map<String, Object> jsonConfiguration;

      @Override
      public TypeOfService getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
      }
    }
```

## Json request

```
{
"serviceConfiguration": {
    "serviceType": "Stripe",
    "jsonConfiguration": {
     .....
     ....
    }}}
```

## Enum class

```java
    public enum TypeOfService {
      STRIPE("Stripe"),
      BRAIN("Brain")
    }
```

## Error I am getting

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot 
construct instance of `com.example.models.payment.ServiceConfiguration` (no Creators, 
like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete 
types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

Any hint to fix it? or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works as expected for me (and i don't see anything wrong with your config). Could you have omitted some final fields from your classes?

Comment: @Chaosfire I have removed final keyword from fields and even added default constructors but still getting `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ServiceConfiguration` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
`

Comment: Can you update question with a reproducible example? As i said, it works for me and i can only randomly guess without one.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with following changes:

1. In specific classes, `@NoArgConstructor` and `@Getter` were enough. The class looks like this:

   ```
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @Getter
   public class StripeServiceConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
       private Map<String, Object> jsonConfiguration;
   }
   ```
2. Added a wrapper class:

   ```
   @Data
   public class ConfigWrapper {
       private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration;
   }
   ```
3. Then, deserialized using the wrapper class as follows:

   ```
   String json = "{\"serviceConfiguration\":{\"serviceType\":\"Stripe\",\"jsonConfiguration\":{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}}}";
   ConfigWrapper config = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ConfigWrapper.class);
   ```
4. `TypeOfService getServiceType();` This method might not be required. So, I cleaned it up. The interface looks like this now:

   ```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                 property = "serviceType")
   @JsonSubTypes({
       @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StripeServiceConfiguration.class, name = "Stripe"),
       @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BrainServiceConfiguration.class, name = "Brain"),
   })
   public  interface ServiceConfiguration {
   }
   ```

Comment: Already tried that and getting

Cannot construct instance of  (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

`public StripeServiceConfiguration() {
  
  }`

Comment: Hey, @AmitPal, please check my above edited answer. I could make it run locally. Please try and let me know.